# Access private or protected properties from Symfony2 repository

Tags: symfony, repository, entity, private

I'm trying to access private properties of an entity from his own repository. By doing PHP tells me I can not access private or protected properties or methods.

I'm just calling a custom repository method created by me, passing an instance of the entity. When i try to get the ID for example, php throws me the error.

How I can access it?

```
public function customMethod($entityInstance)
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
            FROM AcmeMainBundle:Content c
            WHERE 
                c.published = 1 
                AND
                c.id != :id
            ORDER BY c.date DESC'
    )
    ->setParameter('id',$entityInstance->id);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

This is an example of the custom method of my repository. Obviously is just an example, that DQL is not very usefull but when I try to access to $entityInstance->id ...

Can someone helps me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between a `Repository` and an `Entity` is conceptual, not structural. This means that although you know they *are* related, **PHP** doesn't.

If you want to access private members of the `Entity` from the `Repository` you will have to do it like with any other class: using **getters** and **setters**.

Try this:

```
->setParameter('id', $entityInstance->getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as with all normal PHP scripts, if you want to access a private or protected property you have to create a getter. DQL isn't changing anything from the PHP site, it only adds minor changes to the SQL syntax (which is just a string in PHP).

So actually, I don't see what you're trying to say with this question. That DQL should change the way PHP and OO works?